# Java ORM with functions similar to Django's default ORM?

Tags: java, orm, django-models

I'm planning to switch from django to Java, don't ask why :). I've decided to use Play Framework. What I need is an ORM which will allow to mix object oriented approach with native sql.

Something like django's example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#extra

Is there anything in the Java world that has these capabilities?

Example from Django's ORM world, two models: blog and blogEntry (1->N relationship). We are selecting all the blogs with counted blogEntry elements.

```
Blog.objects.extra(
    select={
        'entry_count': 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blog_entry WHERE blog_entry.blog_id = blog_blog.id'
    },
)
```

Comment: Hibernate or iBatis or TopLink would be my suggestions.

Comment: @duffymo is it possible in hibernate to add on the fly extra computed/queried fields in the result?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, but of course Java has bind parameters for dynamic queries.

Comment: I posted an example. You get all the blog objects with an extra field "entry count" populated from a sub-query defined in pure SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something quite like this with JPA, which is the standard persistence API in Java, using its JPQL query language.

Say you have a persistent class called `Blog`, which has a property called `entries` which refers to a set of instances of a class called `BlogEntry`.

You can retrieve all the `Blogs` on their own with this query:

```
select b from Blog b
```

You can then also retrieve the entry count by joining through the `entries` property and counting the results grouped by `Blog`:

```
select b, count(e) from Blog b join b.entries e group by b
```

Now, doing that means that the query will return a list of object arrays, where each array contains a `Blog` and a `Long` for the count. You might like to make this a little more typesafe. If you wrote a class called `BlogWithCount` which had a constructor like this:

```
public BlogWithCount(Blog b, long count)
```

Then you can use a constructor expression:

```
select new org.example.BlogWithCount(b, count(e)) from Blog b join b.entries e group by b
```

This query returns a list of `BlogWithCount` objects, from which you can then retrieve your results in a nice neat way.

When i first wrote this answer, i thought it would be possible to write a simpler version of the count query, like this:

```
select b, count(b.entries) from Blog b
```

But this doesn't work, at least in Hibernate 4.1.4. Looking at the spec, it seems like perhaps it should work, so this might be a bug. I'm not sure.